# how to access from an object created in a different class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragments, a HomeFragment and a SettingsFragment. In the Settingsfragment I have a spinner. Depending on what item is selected in the spinner, i want to either set the maximum of progress bar higher or lower. So I have a string variable (spinnerTime) in settingsfragment class, but I want to have access to this string variable in the home class. How can I do this? Do I have to work with an interface here? Heres the code a function in homefragment class:

```
public void handleProgress(){
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(86400*1000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //EDIT: added thes lines:
        SharedPreferences sp = 
        getContext().getSharedPreferences("spinner", 
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String spinnerTime = sp.getString("spinner", "");
            progress = progress +1;
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);

            if (spinnerTime.equals("1min")){
                progressBar.setMax(60);
            } else if (spinnerTime.equals("30min")){
                progressBar.setMax(1800);
            } else if (spinnerTime.equals("1h")) {
                progressBar.setMax(3600);
            } else if (spinnerTime.equals("24h")) {
                progressBar.setMax(3600*24);
            }
        }
```

The following code shows the settingsfragment class:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    Spinner spinner;
    ImageView ring_spinner;
    String item;
    String spinnerTime;
    TextView tv_timeOfCircle;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.settingsfragment, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ring_spinner = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ring_spinner);
        tv_timeOfCircle = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        handleSpinner();

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void handleSpinner(){
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.numbers, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                spinnerTime = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                //EDIT: added the four following lines to the 
                //settingsfragment class
                sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("spinner", 
                getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putString("spinnerStr", spinnerTime);
                editor.commit();
                Toast showItem = Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
 spinnerTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                showItem.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now of course i have got a cannot resolve symbol "spinnerTime" error. Has somebody an idea to solve this? Id be really grateful for any advice

Comment: Store it using [sharedPreferences](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-preferences-in-android-with-examples/amp/) and retrieve it in your fragment.

Comment: Can you show me how this would work? Because it doesnt work with what I did now...

Comment: It's because your `getString` doesn't match to the proper key, i.e `String spinnerTime = sp.getString("spinner", "");` should be `String spinnerTime = sp.getString("spinnerStr", "");` (how you stored it).